# I am trying to make a game in python. This part only displays the number of lives. But I get this error "missing 1 required positional argument: self"

Tags: arguments

So, I am trying to make a Space War game in python using the turtle module. I am on the part of displaying the number of lives the player has. I only need help with displaying the number of lives but, for it to actually work, I think I can do that myself. I have created a class known as "game2". I used def to give it some attributes and added the player lives. But when I try something, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HUAWEI\OneDrive\Desktop\Space War\test of space war.py", line 225, in 
game2.show_lives()
TypeError: game2.show_lives() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

For more detail, I use IDLE Python 3.11.5 64-bit, if this helps.

This is what I tried.
class game2():
def **init**(self):
self.lives = 3

```
def show_lives(self):
    self.pen.undo()
    msg2 = "Lives: %l" % (self.lives)
    self.pen.penup()
    self.pen.goto(-200, 310)
    self.pen.write(msg2, font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))
```

game2.show_lives()

I was expecting to have it display "Lives:" but it didn't. Instead, I was met with this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HUAWEI\OneDrive\Desktop\Space War\test of space war.py", line 225, in 
game2.show_lives()
TypeError: game2.show_lives() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you did not initialize the `game2` class.

First, the class `game2` should have a corresponding `__init__(self)` function.  There is a problem with this since there isn't a `__init__(self)` function in the class `game2`. Instead there is only a `init(self)` function.

If you intended the `init(self)` function to be `__init__(self)`, then you should change the name of the function to `__init__(self)`. `__init__` is a name for the function for initializing the class.

Secondly, by calling `game2.show_lives()`, you are actually calling the what is called 'static method'. It is because `game2` is not an instance of a class, but rather the class itself. You should first initialize the class by 'calling the class like a function'.

For example, you can do this instead:

```py
running_game2 = game2()
running_game2.show_lives()
```

Now the `running_game2` is an instance, not a class. So you can call the
class function `show_lives()` without sending an instance as `self`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I tried what you suggested, but it didn't work. Still thanks for trying to help me.